# Saving associated records in Laravel

Tags: laravel-4

I'm trying to associated two records together, but it isn't working.

My method for doing this (inside a repository) looks like:

```
public function create(array $data)
{
    // Create the user
    $user = $this->userModel->create([
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email'    => $data['email'],
        'password' => $data['password']
    ]);

    // Create the profile
    $profile = $this->profileModel->create([
        'location' => $data['profile']['location'],
        'bio'      => $data['profile']['bio']
    ]);

    $user->profile()->associate($profile);

    $user->save();

    return true;
}
```

(full source for this can be found here: https://github.com/LimeBlast/prijs/blob/master/app/Prijs/Repository/User/EloquentUser.php#L44)

But I'm getting the error: "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::associate()"

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: It's going to be in the relationship. If in your user model profile is a has one relationship I bet that's your problem.

Comment: The relationship is `hasone` (https://github.com/LimeBlast/prijs/blob/master/app/models/User.php#L40) and `belongsto` in return (https://github.com/LimeBlast/prijs/blob/master/app/models/Profile.php#L10) - what do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$profile->user()->associate($user);
$profile->save();
```

That would be my best guess. You need to call the associate on the object that has the belongsTo method

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I had it backwards.

Comment: I just wanted to add that apparently `$user->profile()->save($profile);` followed by `$user->save();` also works.